# What is the limit of Lovers Leap?

Tags: league-of-legends

Two [new champions](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/featured/champion-xayah-rakan-reveal) have been announced in LoL.

They have an ability that makes them be able to recall together.

What are the limits to this ability? Can the 'non-recaller' jump in at the last second and get some kind of instant recall?

Can somebody with the setup to get on PBE test it and tell us what are the limitations of this ability?

Comment: Being on the PBE means it's not officially released yet. IMO this should be closed, since PBE numbers are subject to change and the Champion isn't even officially out yet

Comment: @Oak I think your reasoning is not valid - see [this meta answer](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5541/163757).

Comment: @Oak As long as it is publicly playable, it is testable. As long as something is testable, an objective (or at the very least, subjective with evidence) answer exists that users of Arqade can find. Therefore it is perfectly fine to ask questions about beta content.

Comment: Also, knowing League of Legends, the timings might change, but they won't change the ability completely before release.

Comment: @MageXy It's not publicly playable. Only a few people have access to the PBE

Comment: @Oak It's not available to every single player, but it is still publicly available. "Public" means anyone who isn't an internal employee who might be limited by an NDA or similar.

Comment: @MageXy PBE is Public Beta Environnement; and anybody can go on it if they want, you just need to setup a few things to get access. It's not something that is closed off by being an employee or something like that.

Comment: @Fredy31 I agree. I can kind of see where Oak is coming from - in order to get access to the PBE, you need to be approved by Riot, which can take a couple weeks or months sometimes (unlike something like Overwatch's PTR, which is available to everyone without requiring approval). However, any player can apply to access the PBE, and any player can be approved, which is what makes it public.

Comment: @MageXy It's like the Gwent Beta, (or the Overwatch Beta, before release) You have to apply and then you might be accepted into the PBE program?

Comment: @Fredy31 Correct. Or at least, that's the case when I applied and got in three years ago. I don't think it's changed since then.

Comment: You apply, but once you're accepted, you wait in "line" until they call on you. I'm in PBE right now, and I waiting a couple years or more to get my turn. It's not a literal line, they pick players based on behavior, champions played, how often you play, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tested this on the PBE last night. Based on my tests, the only limiting factor in whether you can join the recall is your ping.

Contrary to what it may look like, simply walking up to the recalling player (referred to as the recaller) is not enough to join the recall. The recallee must *also* hit the Recall skill while in the small AoE indicator of the recaller. I assume this is to prevent accidental teleports from happening.

Because it takes some time for the recall command to travel from your own computer to the server, it might take a short while to join the recall. However, the recallee will join up as soon as the command is received. When I played yesterday, my ping was about 80, and I was able to join a recall with (approximately) half a second left before the warp happened.

Comment: So as long as your recall has started while being in the circle, you will recall at the same time as the one who has initiated the recall? I would have guessed that it would reset the recall to a minimum duration before it actually recalls

Comment: @Fredy31 If you join the recall at any point, the recallee's channel time is reduced to the remaining channel time of the recaller, so they will both back at the same time. As far as I can tell, there's no channel time reset for joining later.

Comment: Welp, I have the feeling this will get nerfed soon.

Comment: @Fredy31 I doubt it. It's a very niche benefit, and it only works when Xayah is paired with a Raken support (which will not be 100% of the time). Using this in an actual fight is dangerous because it risks both players getting killed instead of one person acting as a distraction while the other gets away.

Comment: You have a point, In pro play with near perfect coordination it might be OP (if they can pick both of them, which I doubt) but with randos yeah, no chance thats gonna happen anyway.

Comment: Nice. I was going to buy and play them last night on the PBE, but the store wasn't working for me.

Comment: @mbomb007 They are currently free champions on the PBE (available to everyone without purchase). I suspect Riot knew their PBE shop would be overwhelmed with anxious players buying the new champion, so they just made them free so some testing could get done.

Comment: Yeah, I saw, but I wanted to buy them. Rerolling wasn't working either.